# Expression type'@Ivalue String?' is ambiguous without more context Error

Tags: ios, swift

I keep getting this error and I have no idea why, here is the code that causes it:

```
@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    sliderBet.text = "\(Int(slider.value * Int(String(myScore.text!)!)))"
}
```

I am trying to multiply the value of the slider by another variable that is taken from a UILabel, which is why I have to convert it to a string and than into an Int

Comment: What is `slider`? Shouldn't that be `sender`?

Comment: in the new Xcode update slider.value has the same functionality as sender.value. essentially I am trying to multiply the value of the slider by another variable, myScore

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `"\(Int(slider.value) * Int(myScore.text!)!)"` better (`"\(Int(slider.value) * Int(myScore.text) ?? 1)"`)? Creating a string from a string is redundant.

Comment: that works but the value of the slider is between 0 and 1 so it need to be a float. if I replaced the code with: sliderBet.text = "\(Int(Float(slider.value) * Int(myScore.text!)))" then I get the same error but it says @Ivalue Float is ambiguous now and need more context

Comment: If you need `Double` then it's still simpler as `value` is already `Double`: `"\(slider.value * Double(myScore.text) ?? 1.0)"`

Comment: using that solution still returns the original error for an ambiguous String :/

Comment: Try `"\(slider.value * (Double(myScore.text) ?? 1.0))"`

Comment: Same result. The program works fine when I run I don't try to make the slider value a float

Comment: Is `slider` the `IBOutlet` of the affected `UISlider`? Does `sender.value` work?

Comment: both slider and sender work the same, I think the issue is with the .text, which is underlined in red. for example, I can't assign testVariable = Int(myScore.text) without the same error

Answer (score 1):

Although you know that *the value of the slider is between 0 and 1 so it need to be a **float***, why dare you use `Int` or `Double`?

```
@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    sliderBet.text = "\(Int(sender.value * (Float(myScore.text ?? "0") ?? 0))))"
}
```

`(Float(myScore.text ?? "0") ?? 0)` looks a little bit long, but it converts `myScore.text` safely to **`Float`**. When `myScore.text` is nil or is not valid as a number, it returns `0 as Float`, instead of crashing.